# Voltage/current issue in a circuit

Tags: batteries, nodemcu, sim, iot

I am working on a project where I have a 3.7 V battery connected to a SIM module. The battery has a maximum voltage of 4.2V and a cutoff voltage of 2.65 V. A NodeMCU is also connected to the circuit along with a GPS module.

The problem is that the SIM module needs around 3.6 V to keep working optimally and once the battery voltage falls below 3.6, the SIM stops working.

To counter this I got a voltage booster that can output a voltage of 3.6 V all the time. To my surprise, with the voltage booster in the circuit the devices behave abnormally. Sometimes they take a very long time to start working properly and sometimes one component works but the other component does not work. Without the voltage booster, the device works 100% of the time. What could be the problem?

Edit: I adjusted the output voltage of the voltage booster to 3.6V

Comment: Improperly chosen voltage booster? Impossible to tell without data sheets and measurements!

Comment: Please supply a link to the pdf data sheet of the voltage booster.

Comment: @sinabala https://components101.com/modules/mt3608-2a-dc-dc-step-up-power-module here is a link to the voltage booster module. This isnt the datasheet but should have all the necessary information

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. At the very least, a specification of maximum load in the given configuration is missing. Especially a maximum current vs input/output voltage. Generally, this is just an underspecified random boost converter module without the necessary Datasheet. Doesn't do what *you* think it should, but never came with the data sheet to claim it would...

Comment: <<<For a boost converter, the output voltage should always be greater than the input voltage. >>> It probably does not ... You should use a buck/boost converter.

Comment: Somethiing like this https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slpp104/slpp104.pdf?ts=1708402607792&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F